# scandir access is denied from httpd, but not from command line

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I have a script that attempts to use `scandir()` on a network location. The script worked fine up until about a week ago. Now, I receive "Access is denied." If I execute the script via command line, it works as expected. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Check your access to this folder. Your local user, started script - has access, but httdp user (or www-data in some distributions) - no.

Comment: this is in a windows environment, by the way

Comment: @StephenKnoth Are you executing the command line as the user running xampp or as an administrator? Is the network location mapped to a drive or are you using [UNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Uniform_Naming_Convention) paths?

Comment: it is mapped, but i know the drive and the unc path, and i've tried. i am on windows xp, so there is no run as administrator. i have a feeling the issue is what user i'm running php as. i just tried to make a c# script to do the same thing, then call it via php, and got a system.unauthorizedaccess exception or something. so it's definitely the user.. and you can't change what user xampp runs at apparently.